# Mocking method in class that is already mocked

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to set the return value of a method for a class I'm mocking:

```
foo.py

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}

class Beef:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    def run(self):
        val = self.foo.bar()
        return val['a']
```

```
test_foo.py

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from foo import Beef

class TestBeef(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('foo.Foo')
    def test_run(self, mock_foo):
        mock_foo.bar.return_value = {'a': 'x'}  # how to do this?
        beef = Beef()
        assert result == {'a': 'x'}
```

This fails to mock the method.
Since this is a simplified example, there is a reason why I need to mock the entire Foo class. In my actual scenario, there is a lot of initialization code.

How can I mock the method of a class that has been mocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by overriding the instance's `foo`'s method

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from foo import Beef

class TestBeef(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('foo.Foo')
    def test_run(self, mock_foo):
        beef = Beef()
        beef.foo.bar.return_value = {'a': 'x'}
        assert result == {'a': 'x'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `test_foo.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from foo import Beef, Foo

class TestBeef(unittest.TestCase):
  
    def test_run(self):
        mock.object.patch(Foo, 'bar', return_value={'a': 'x'})
        beef = Beef()
        assert result == {'a': 'x'}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I still need to mock `Foo` initilization

Comment: Because you want to instantiate Foo? So why not mocking __init__ as well?